# how to download file from web, windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, html-agility-pack

what i am trying to do is go to this (http://www.dubstep.net/track/5439) loop through the html looking for href. once it finds a # it takes the href url before the #. and then down load the file from that url before the #. now the code below does everything up till downloading. now how would i download the file from url t?

```
public async void songsLoad()
    {
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("1");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        //use HAP's HtmlWeb instead of WebClient
        var htmlweb = new HtmlWeb();
        // load HtmlDocument from web URL
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = await htmlweb.LoadFromWebAsync("http://www.dubstep.net/track/5439");
        int i = 0;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        //use LINQ API to select all `<a>` having `href` attribute
        var links = doc.DocumentNode
                       .DescendantsAndSelf("a")
                       .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("href", null) != null);
        foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
        {

            HtmlAttribute href = link.Attributes["href"];
            if (href != null)
            {
                list.Add(href.Value);
                i++;
                if (href.Value == "#")
                {
                    int t = i - 2;
                    Uri test = new Uri(list[t]);
                    start(test);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

below is code that will download the file i want, but this is in a console application.. 
how would i achieve this?

```
 public static void start(Uri t)
    {

        string fileName1 = "t", myStringWebResource = null;

        // Create a new WebClient instance.
        using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            myWebClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
            myWebClient.DownloadProgressChanged += myWebClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
            myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(t, "file.mp3");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying `LoadFromWebAsync()` doesn't work?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you could probably try a regular `HttpClient`.

Comment: @FilipSkakun no, but could you give an example of how to use it?
also ill look in to the httpclient

Comment: It seems like you already are trying to use it in your code, so I'm asking if it is working or not.

Comment: @FilipSkakun if your talking about myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(t, "file.mp3"); then no, that does not work in windows store app. but there is a htmlweb.LoadFromWebAsync but i do not know how to use it

Comment: @MichaelLapan AFAIK HAP's `LoadFromWebAsync()` suppose to download html file from web and load it to `HtmlDocument`, can't be used to download just any kind of file. Maybe try using `HttpClient` as suggested by Nate, but I haven't really work with it, so can't provide example

Comment: @NateDiamond could you either link me to an good esay to understand example or post one? ive looked at a few useing httpClient, but a litte confused on them still.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've usually been doing it is with a [`BackgroundDownloader`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Net/WebFile.cs) which might be an overkill, but in case of a simple html file you can download a string - just call

```
string htmlString = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(uri);
```

...then you should be able to load it with something like `htmlDocument.Load(htmlString);`